# Unsigned underflow doesn't happen in subscript operator, why?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I have always thought the next example is undefined behaviour (accessing array out of bounds):

```
int main()
{
    int* a= new int[3];
    a[0] = 100;
    a++;
    
    unsigned long index = 0;
    
    printf("%d\n", a[-1]);
    printf("%d\n", a[index - 1]);
    printf("%ul\n", index - 1);
}
```

However, this outputs just fine:

```
100
100
4294967295l
```

Why doesn't underflow happen in subscript operator?

Comment: There is no such thing as unsigned underflow, for more reasons than one.

Comment: You have UB in `printf("%ul\n", index - 1);` because that format specifier is wrong, it should be `%lu`

Comment: @toxic [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means anything can happen, including the appearance of a working program.

Comment: @Fareanor the pointer `a` was incremented after assigning an array to it, so `-1` is within bounds

Comment: Undefined behaviour is not "the result is wrong". Undefined behaviour is not "there is an error message". Undefined behaviour is not "the program crashes". Undefined behaviour is not "the result is wrong OR there is an error message OR the program crashes".

Comment: fine looking output is no contradiction to undefined behavior. The first comment explains quite well the flaw in your logic. Another example I often use to illustrate this flaw is using `+` to multiply two numbers. `2+2` is the product of `2` and `2`, though that doesnt make the method less broken. Wrong code is not guaranteed to produce wrong output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why doesn't underflow happen in subscript operator?

`printf("%d\n", a[-1]);` has defined behaviour. Pointer arithmetic works with any integral type, so the `signed int` value `-1` is added to `a`, resulting in an in-bounds access, to an element that was initialised.

`printf("%d\n", a[index - 1]);` has undefined behaviour. `index - 1` is a mixed-rank integral expression, and `unsigned long` has a greater<sup>1</sup> rank than `int`, so it is an unsigned expression, equivalent to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()`. Adding this to `a` is out of bounds, thus undefined behaviour. Because the standard places no requirements on the observed behaviour, printing 100 is conformant.

`printf("%ul\n", index - 1);` has undefined behaviour. `lu` is the correct format specifier for `unsigned long`.

1. Equal ranks also result in conversion to unsigned, so it would need to be `unsigned short` to have defined behaviour.

Comment: A variant of C++'s old `if (index < -1) std::cout << "Impossible!\n";` surprise.

Answer (score -4):

Here's an excerpt from [MSVC doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/subscript-operator?view=msvc-170)

"
**Syntax** :

```
postfix-expression [ expression ]
```

Usually, the value represented by *postfix-expression* is a pointer value, such as an array identifier, and *expression* is an integral value (including enumerated types).

"

The subscript is treated as an int. Even if `index - 1` underflows and is equal to `0xFFFFFFFF`, when converted to int it is `-1` and has the same effect as a[-1].

Comment: *"an integral value"* does not mean only `int` - there are a lot of different integral types in C++